# How avoid user authentication for one single url in htaccess?

Tags: server-setup, htaccess, .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/wp-content*$" AdminUri

AuthUserFile /public_html/.htpasswd

AuthType Basic

AuthName "My Secret Folder"

Require valid-user
```

I set up authentication in my site as above. I want to remove it for one URL i.e. `abc.com/e-avis`, but I need authentication for all other URLS